# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'name' of 'req.body' as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mern, body-parser

I'm Currently trying to learn MERN Stack web development. I'm encountering an unusual problem.
So I'm trying to use Postmate to try and input data from the body to the database. When doing so from the server.js file, it would work but when I tried to do it from a different file, the console won't recognize the inputted data

here's my controller file (when i console log the req.body it just returns undefined)

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import StudentsData from '../models/students.js';
 
const router = express.Router();

export const createStudent = async (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    const newStudentsData = new StudentsData({ name });

    try {
        await newStudentsData.save();

        res.status(201).json( newStudentsData );
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}
```

Here is my routes file

```
import express from 'express';

import { createStudent, getStudents, deleteStudent, updateStudent } from '../controllers/students.js';

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/insertdata', createStudent);

export default router;
```

here's my models file

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const studentsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    roll_no: Number,
    gender: String
});

const studentsData = mongoose.model('studentsData', studentsSchema);

export default studentsData;
```

and this is my server.js file

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import router from './routes/students.js';

const app = express();

app.use('/students', router);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true}));


mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://merntutor:merntutor123@cluster0.txjnr.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
})
.then(() => {
    console.log("DB CONNECTED");
});
const PORT = 8000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app is running at ${PORT}`);
});
```

on the body, I inputted

```
{
    "name": "test"
}
```

Comment: Seems name got double bracket at `new StudentsData({ name });`?
name already be a object as `req.body.name = {"name": "test"}` but it has bracket of object like 
`{ {"name": "test"}}`

Comment: Oh yeah. My bad, I corrected it just now and the error still occurs

Comment: Because app.use(bodyParser...) isn't used in controller file (which json object should be parsed) so `req.body` isn't undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Please write `app.use(express.json());` before `app.use('/students', router);` in `server.js` file. `express.json()` middleware should run before all your routes.

Also, do you think you need `bodyParser` as [`.json()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json) and [`.urlencoded()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) are now already available with express?

Comment: Ah. I tried your first suggestion and now it works. I  don't quite get what you mean on the second statement tho. Could you elaborate? Or does it not matter now that the program works?

Comment: Oh and can you also explain how this works, I tried making a similar program a while ago following a tutorial on youtube and the code works without using the ```app.use(express.json());``` syntax

Comment: With Express [4.x](https://expressjs.com/en/changelog/4x.html#4.16.0), you don't need `bodyParser` as separate middleware. Express provides you with `express.json()` and `express.urlencoded()`.

Answer (score 0):

why **console.log(req.body)** if you have already **assignd** the value in the **const {name}** shouldn't you **console.log(name)**
that what I think hope it is any use to you

Comment: I tried that before and it also outputs undefined on the terminal.
The problem is that the program cannot take data from the body with req body from the controller file while it can from the server.js

Comment: try adding the body parser middle-ware in your controller file also